# Present perfect vs past

Tags: difference, tense

I've wanted to tell someone that this was how I wanted to close the week since 2016 when I stopped sailing...
But I didn't and I still don't know what was correct

> 1. That's how I wanted to close the week since 2016 when I stopped sailing.
> 2. That's how I've wanted to close the week since 2016 when I stopped sailing.

Comment: No 1 explains how you wanted (in the past) to do something. No 2 explains how you continue to want to do something. Both are correct. They say different things.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, both answers would be correct depending on what you're trying to say.

*Simple past*: you wanted to close the week that way **from 2016 to a certain moment in your closer past**.

*Present perfect*: you wanted to close the week that way **in 2016 and you still do**.

Comment: Yes, both are equally correct. However, if the OP is an examinee, he/she should choose the second one, because many a time questions are framed around the certain key words like 'since' in this case.